# Query which joins tables and returns cursor

Tags: java, android, sqlite, cursor

It's my first post here.

I've run into a problem when creating a one-to-many relationship among tables and then reading it. For example, I have a `User` table and `Tweet` table. A user can have a lot of tweets, which means that the `Tweet` table contains a foreign key as a reference to a user. So, this a typical scenario when I use a join command in order to get users with their tweets.

So, here is what I would do in order to make such a query:

```
String table = "users LEFT OUTER JOIN tweets ON users.user_id=tweets.user_id";
return database.query(table, null, null, null, null,null,null);
```

So then I get a `Cursor`, but how do I read this data?

Your help will be highly appreciated!

Comment: Is there any tutorial that does not explain this?

Comment: @CL, Well, I know how to read data that you get from one table, but in this case a user can have a lot of tweets, which means that I need somehow to connect those tweets between users. Let's say that there are 10 users and each one has 10 tweets. So if use this loop: `while(cursor.moveToNext()){ // retrieve data}` I will be getting the same users for 10 times. Do understand my point? How would you approach this?

Comment: Use distinct on the user_id to get unique list of users? If you can't modify the query, consider using other one or just iterate on your cursor eith respect to old data

Comment: @Mr.V Edit the question so that it asks what you actually want to know.